# Sails.js - PATH variable - sails command not recognized

Tags: node.js, cmd, npm, sails.js, path-variables

After I npm installed Sails.js on Windows Server 2008, "sails" command is not recognized.

Can someone give me a hint on what values to use in the PATH variable? As I understand it is Node.exe that runs the sails.js file. But if I try tunning "node sails.js" command in cmd, it recognizes it, but can't find some of the dependencies.

On my Windows 7 machine everything installed and is running like a charm.

Comment: Did you install sails globally? i.e. `npm install -g sails`

Comment: Yes I did install it globally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up writing a batch file and putting it into system32 folder "`c:\Windows\System32\sails.bat`" with this one line:

```
node C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js
```

Now, `sails lift` works well.

Comment: I had this same problem but I had to add the `lift` command to the batch file. Passing the `lift` command from the command line did not work. `node C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js lift`

Comment: Weird. Windows + Sails.js = not the best combo.

Comment: Yeah, and Windows Server 2008 acts weird as well.

Comment: For ubuntu.. I ended up adding this line in `.bashrc` file

`alias sails='node /home/<user>/.node/lib/node_modules/sails/bin/sails.js'`

Answer (score 6):

Did you try using the -g (for global) option?

If I use:

```
npm install -g sails
```

On either Windows 8.1 or Server 2012R2, I find it is accessible from the path just fine.

Answer (score 5):

1. Install sails globally
   npm install -g sails
2. If you have right to add Environment variables (Start =>  Computer=> Properties=>Advance system setting => Advance(Tab)=>Environment Variable(button at the bottom) => User variable for ...(the top one) => find "PATH" => edit ) and add the location of your npm folder (C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm) (this folder can be hidden so enable show hidden folder to locate your path)
3. open new cmd window and enjoy sails :)

Answer (score 2):

it looks line a `sails.cmd` file is create in the global npm folder, so if you add this folder `C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm` to your PATH sails will be a recognized command, and will accept all valid parameters (tried `new` and `lift` and both look OK).

In this way all other node packaged that are command line based should work, if they follow this convention to install on Windows (I think this is the case).

I don't have a Windows Server 2008 to test on but it seems it fails to do this process automatically, as it does on Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

If you add a .bat file in system32, remember to add parameters to the bat script. Found that out after trying some of the solutions previously posted here. My example:

```
C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Roaming\npm\sails %1 %2
```

Sails is not a directory there, it's a file. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

you can add new 'node' commands like 'npm', using batch scripting.

1. Create a sails.cmd file in your desktop. (new text file -> rename to
   'sails.cmd').
2. Right-click on sails.cmd and select Edit.
3. Copy and paste this code into your sails.cmd:

   ```
   @ECHO OFF
   SET arguments=%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
   node %APPDATA%\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js %arguments%
   ```
4. Save and copy your sails.cmd into your Node.js installation
   directory, for example: C:\Program Files\nodejs
5. And now everything with sails.js on windows are very simple. Just run this command in your terminal:

`sails` or `sails -v` or whatever you want with `sails`! ;)

Enjoy!

---

**UPDATE!**

At this time I highly recommend using the WizofOz solution. It is the most correct way to proceed in a node.js environment.

Answer (score 1):

For ubuntu 16.+

Get prefix of node

> npm get prefix

look loke this : '/home/ubuntu/node'

now open bash_profile

> sudo vim ~/.profile

Add this line if you already have path in this file

> export PATH="$PATH:/home/ubuntu/node/bin"

if you node prefix is diff replace with your prefix

> export PATH="$PATH:{ your-node-prefix }/bin"

Answer (score 0):

To help clarify for Windows 8 users. After installing sails globally if receiving errors do this:

1. Create a sails.txt file

Add this

> node C:\Users\XXXXXXX\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js new
>   node C:\Users\XXXXXXX\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js lift

2. Now re-save it as sails.bat
3. Add this new file to your C:\Windows\System32

Navigate to the folder you want to hold your new sails app. Scaffold the app with the following command:

> sails new

If you don't want a front-end, instead type:

> sails new --no-frontend

We can also launch the app using the lift command:

> sails lift

This will launch our new app on port 1337

Answer (score 0):

For MAC Users, try this (run the following on your terminal)

```
export PATH="/Users/username/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"
```