# Running sails throwing invalid character error

Tags: sails.js

I have installed sails successfully using npm install sails -g 
I am running Windows 7. When I tried to run the 'sails' command, got error saying "command not found". Then I included the corresponding bin folder in PATH env variable. Then getting javascript error while trying to run 'sails' command.
ERROR::

Line:   1

Char:   1

Error:  Invalid character

Code:   800A03F6

Source: Microsoft JScript compilation error

Answer (score 5):

This error message is not linked to Node, but to **Windows Scripting Host**.

On Windows `.js` files are associated to **Windows Scripting Host** by default, so the script will not be run with Node.

Open a file explorer and find a JavaScript file, you can check by the icon that it's not considered JavaScript.

Open a JavaScript file's properties and in the *associated programs* (or `open with`), link the Node.js exe file to open that kind of files.

The error should no longer appear.

Comment: I had this problem with madge npm library and this answer fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you need to run sails.js with node.bat. To do so, first make sure your path variable is updated with the location of your node install:

```
PATH=%PATH%;c:\program files\nodejs
```

Then make a c:\program files\nodejs\sails.cmd file with the following contents

```
node C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js %1 %2 %3 %4 %5
```

Replace XXXX with your user profile name. Save it and you should be all sorted. Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107706/sails-js-path-variable-sails-command-not-recognized) for some inspiration.

Comment: After I followed the below steps, still getting the same error.Not sure what went wrong.I have attached the snails installation and env setup screenshots to my original post please refer.1. Installed with this command  npm install -g sails 2.created snails.cmd  with  node C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 and saved under c:\program files\nodejs\sails.cmd 3.set env  as c:\program files\nodejs and C:\Users\rp091176\AppData\Roaming\npm\

Comment: Is the contents of `sails.cmd` `node C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js %1 %2 %3 %4 %5` or `node C:\Users\rp091176\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js %1 %2 %3 %4 %5`? (it should be the latter)