# lighthouse-batch throws java script error

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse

When i tried to run the below , throws java script error in index.js file

C:>lighthouse-batch -s https://airhorner.com,https://housing.com

Does any one has  encounter the same?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Install `node.js` first.

Comment: @wOxxOm  I did aleardy and have been testing using lighthouse

Comment: Then it's not in the PATH or maybe you didn't install lighthouse via `npm`. Try [running the js file manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30771461).

Comment: After I followed the below steps, still getting the same error.Not sure what went wrong.I have attached the snails installation and env setup screenshots to my original post please refer.1. Installed with this command npm install -g sails 2.created snails.cmd with node C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 and saved under c:\program files\nodejs\sails.cmd 3.set env as c:\program files\nodejs and C:\Users\rp091176\AppData\Roaming\npm\

Comment: After trying several ways, finally i am able to run successfully with this command lighthouse-batch -s [url1],[url2],[url3] -g ex : lighthouse-batch -s https://airhorner.com,https://housing.com -g , but for long urls it's getting same old error.I have set my bat file as @echo on
lighthouse-batch -h -s https://airhorner.com,https://housing.com,https://xxxx.xxxx.com/sc/login.html?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fxxxx.xxx.xx.corp%2Fauth%2Fcallback&scope=&client_id=stfenix-qa1 -g.Is there a way to pass urls list in the txt file sequentially and pass in bat file

Comment: also needed to add -g on the end of the command